# definition of countable infinite character without the use of N

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Let's say a family of sets, $F$ has finite character iff $\forall X: [X \in F \leftrightarrow \forall E \subseteq X: E \, finite \rightarrow E \in F)$

or more precise: let's say a family $F$ has character k iff $\forall X: X \in F \leftrightarrow (\forall E \subseteq X: |E| \leq k \rightarrow E \in F)$.

Now I'm wondering, what would be a sensible definition for a family to be of (at most) countable infinite character?)

And can you think of an example for a family of countable infinite character, but not finite character?

EDIT: Would something like $\forall X: X \in F \leftrightarrow (\forall E \subseteq X: |E| \leq |\omega| \rightarrow E \in F)$ be legitimate? (whereby $\omega$ is the smallest inductive set, i.e. the set-theory-description of $\mathbb{N_0}$)

EDIT: Would the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ be such an example and if so, how could we write this without using $\mathbb{N}$? And would there be a maximal element in it?

Comment: You ask about "sensible," but that's going to be relative to a possible application, so it might help if you can comment on what that might be. Given the definition of "at most countable character" in your edit, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is such a set, though I'm not sure how or why you would define the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ without reference to $\mathbb{N}$. And obviously power sets have a maximal element.

Comment: No, $\omega$  is wrong.  You want either $\aleph_0$ or |$\omega_0$|.

Comment: In the first line of symbolic logic you have unbalanced [ )  and all such lines have ambiguous  quantifer scopes.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Thanks for commenting! You are right, $|\omega|$ is what I meant (in my definition it contains the empty set). But what do you mean by your second comment?

Comment: Maybe instead of interjections, either edit the information into the question, or make one concentrated edit at the end?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'll do this, thanks!

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Thank you for your comment! I edited the question, maybe/hopefully it is clearer now? I am not so sure myself, how a "sensible" definition has to look like, but I mean by it that in only uses the language of set theory, i.e. not uses $\mathbb{N}$, but if $\mathbb{N}$ is needed, it uses $\omega$ instead.     You are right that the power set has a maximal element, the union. Someone suggested the family of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (That comment seems deleted.) Do you know how to express this (i.e. $\mathbb{R}$ ) in the language of set theory or do you have another example?